# pgpool postgresql ec2 instance

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2, pgpool

I am trying to setup pgpool2 with postgresql. I have both on different ec2 instances. I am going through the tutorial and I am trying to create a database with

```
createdb -U <username> -p <port> -h <IPpostgres> bench_replication
```

It then prompts me for a password. The user does not have any password.

```
createdb: could not connect to database template1: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

Do I need to set up SSH keys?

Comment: 1. How have you checked that the PostgreSQL user doesn't have a password? 2. Have you checked the authentication method set up on the server in your pg_hba.conf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a password for the PostgreSQL user or set pg_hba.conf to allow trusted connections.